# ZenCoding in Vim expands css-properties incorrectly

Tags: css, vim, emmet

I am using Vim with ZenCoding
I have found a problem occured when expanding abbreviature to a css-property

In the documentation it is said that:

```
.foo{pos:a
```

Might be expanded to:

```
.foo{position:absolute;
```

While in real life the result is:

```
 <foo></foo>
 position:absolute;
```

So the plugin expands all the elements from the start of line, but seems it must to start  either from `{` symbol when we write the first rule of selector, either from `;` in the other case.

What's the problem?

Comment: Where do you see that in the documentation? `zencoding.txt` does not contain anything like that

Comment: I've seen this in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzdWsAETp5Y#t=07m32s

I can't find this in documentation now, but I sure that it must work like this

Comment: Yes, but Vim is not officially supported. The Zen coding plug-in for vim does not do what this video shows.

Comment: probably, this is fixed in latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The real/actual zen coding have no official support for vim, afaik. I use this vim zencoding by mattn > http://mattn.github.com/zencoding-vim. This one works great!

Comment: Yes, that's the plugin I am using and the described problem is with this plugin, also :(

Comment: Are you in a css file or in a html file? I tried mine and it's working fine. Be sure your in css filetype, to know, enter :set filetype